# "Baggage not Checked Through" - Is this a Self-Transfer with Trip.com?

Tags: luggage, self-transfer

I'm looking at tickets from trip.com to go from MSP -> LAX -> TPE.

This particular flight has a "Baggage not checked through" comment, but not a "self-transfer" comment.

I'm a little unsure of what this means -- do I just have to pick up my luggage and drop it off at a transfer station?

I'm assuming I'd have to exit and go through security again based on the way LAX is set up (going from domestic to international terminal), but does this mean that I'd have to go to the China Airlines counter at LAX and get my China Airlines ticket from LAX to TPE (which seems a little tight on a 90-mn transfer at LAX).

Thank you!

[image: Flight information screenshot showing "1h31m transfer in Los Angeles with 'Different Terminal' and 'Baggage not checked through' warnings]

Comment: What is weird is that DL and CI definitely interline because of Skyteam membership

Comment: I've noticed every flight I've searched on Trip.com recently (last 3 or 4 weeks) have said the same thing "Baggage not checked through" and I've been wondering if it's a glitch in their system

Comment: 91 minutes is too little for a transfer in LAX even if you don't have to claim and recheck your bags. I say from experience that if you're starting a journey at LAX Terminal B (Tom Bradley International Terminal), you need to arrive there at least 3 hours in advance at minimum. The main bottlenecks are waiting in line for and completing security and walking to your gate in the massive gate area (which may require walking through the long tunnel to the 2xx gates). Not having to check bags shaves off 30 minutes which leaves 2.5 hours as a minimum.

Comment: There is an airside access between Terminal 3 and Tom Bradley International Terminal being built, but it hasn't finished yet, and in the meantime you'll have to exit to the landside area and clear security again in the latter terminal. I think they do operate airside bus shuttles on request which removes the need to re-clear security, but I'd recommend double-checking this with Delta.

Comment: That's potentially a legal CYA provision that they proactively put on every flight so that they not need to track this and are off the hook if it doesn't work out. Lesson learned: DON'T BOOK WITH AN OTA (unless you really know what you are doing). Book directly with the airline if any possible

Comment: Self transfer means you have two separate tickets, and if you miss your second flight for any reason (including if the first one is delayed), the second operator is under no obligation to help you out.  Baggage not checked through means simply that you need to collect your bags and check them in again.  In my experience this is common when transferring from domestic to international, or vice versa, in the United States.  Bags are never checked through for self transfers, but sometimes not for other flights.

Comment: @RichardSmith bags not checked through is the normal way of doing things for international-to-domestic in the US, not for domestic-to-international (on a single ticket).

Answer (score 5):

Searching for that flight on [China Airline](https://www.china-airlines.com/us/en)'s website doesn't have any warning about baggage.

When sold directly through an airline, you are certain that you are on a single ticket and that your baggage will follow you (short checking, which is picking your bag at a transit point, is usually a **VERY** pricey option (like $300/bag) to curb hidden-city ticketing).

I assume a glitch with trip.com, and anyway, I would **NEVER** recommend buying from an OTA (Online Travel Agency like trip.com), and only buy from an airline (unless the price difference is big, in this case think about it), it can save you many headaches.

Comment: Something weird here… Neither Delta nor Google Flights find that connection.

Comment: Indeed, but it's definitely sold by CI